# Can we upgrade Amazon linux to amazon linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I have my existing servers on Amazon Linux, now we are planning to upgrade it to amazon linux2. How do we do that?

Do we have a set of steps to upgrade or do we need to launch a new Ec2 instance using Amazon Linux2 Image and re-install our apps on top of it?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Amazon Linux 2 FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/):

> **Can I perform an in-place upgrade from an existing version of Amazon Linux AMI to Amazon Linux 2?**
>
> No, an in-place upgrade from the existing Amazon Linux image to Amazon Linux 2 is not supported. We recommend that you test your application on a fresh installation of Amazon Linux 2 first before migrating.